# Can you install Ubuntu from a liveCD via vnc or similar?

Tags: system-installation, vnc, live-cd

It is possible with other distros! If so, how do you do it?

Comment: What other distros is this possible with?

Comment: I don't remember, I was told by a client. Probably Fedora, or SuSe.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that I can think of is booting to the liveCD environment, bring up a VPN server like [x11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/), connect remotely, then manage the install.

I'm confused though what advantage this gives you, as you still require a physical presense to put in the CD and do other things. I suppose you could do enough automation to grub to boot from an ISO, and automate the ISO so that it automatically starts the VPN server, but that seems like a huge amount of work for such a small problem.

Comment: Well.. it would be nice if the LiveCD could so that automatically. if it does not find a head(i.e. monitor that is connected), it could automatically start this. The use case are devices that do not necessarily have a screen connected or proper input devices connected. I.e. multimedia devices etc.